# PHP parsing XML with invalid character

Tags: php

I am getting an xml file from a webservice.

Unfortunately the file contains character code 2 (\u0002), which breaks the parser.

So I'm trying to remove all character code 2's, but I get wierd results just when trying to do a simple string replace.

To test this, I created a php file named test.php with the following content:

```
<?
$aaa="Hi"+chr(2)+"There"+chr(2)+"Rick";
$aaa = str_replace($aaa,chr(2),"");
echo $aaa;
?>
```

I'm running this from the command line:

php test.php

When I run this I get a blank string.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes your result would be black because `PHP` uses `.` for [concatenation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php)  and not `+`

You should change

```
$aaa="Hi"+chr(2)+"There"+chr(2)+"Rick";
```

To

```
$aaa="Hi".chr(2)."There".chr(2)."Rick";
```

Also also from [PHP DOC](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

```
 mixed str_replace ( mixed $search , mixed $replace , mixed $subject [, int &$count ] )
```

You should also change

```
$aaa = str_replace($aaa,chr(2),"");
```

To

```
$aaa = str_replace(chr(2),"",$aaa);
```